# With rotation, is it computationally more efficient to use quaternions?

Tags: trigonometry, linear-transformations, rotations

When coding rotation in 3D graphics/games, is it computationally more efficient to use quaternions in all circumstances? Say I'm not rotating an airplane or something prone to gimbal lock. Maybe I just want to rotate a 3D character along one axis (y, a shooter for example) or make a 2D character rotate along the Z axis. Should I stick to quaternions or is there a case where I should use a rotation matrix based on trig identities?

For the rotation matrices based on trig identities I mean:
[Rotation about each axis in 3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhaaE.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is really a CS question if anything. FWIW I would assume quarternions would be more efficient until you reach the graphics engine when you probably need to convert to matrices. IIRC you can use quarternions on the GPU with hacks but most engines just use matrices

Comment: Quaternions are pointless for 2D rotations; you might as well use complex numbers to rotate x and y, and leave z unchanged

Comment: For 3D rotations, quaternions are more efficient to compose, but matrices are more efficient to apply. Multiplying two quaternions requires $16$ scalar multiplications, while multiplying two $3\times3$ matrices requires $27$ scalar multiplications. On the other hand, multiplying a quaternion by a vector (in the "sandwich product") requires $24$ scalar multiplications, while multiplying a $3\times3$ matrix by a vector requires only $9$ scalar multiplications.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who answered! Helps a lot and I am satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Quaternions are computationally more efficient than rotation matrices since 4 scalars comprise each quaternion and must be stored. In contrast, a rotation matrix has 9 scalars (3x3 matrix). In terms of chained 3D rotations, a rotation matrix needs 45 operations (multiplications, additions, and subtractions), while the quaternions require just 28. Keep in mind that both solutions need to be orthogonalized at some point to avoid the computation of scaled rotations.

[Look here for a more detailed answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Performance_comparisons).